# How can I help review/test a Webform CiviCRM PR

Tags: webform-civicrm, developer, user

Please describe the exact steps and requirements - of what I can do if I see a PR in https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pulls - that I think would be useful to our organization.

Answer (score 5):

You will need ssh access to the code base (on your server):

First: when working on latest code edits you may need to pull in the latest edits (that may not have been released yet) -> for example:

`karins-macbook-pro-2:webform_civicrm sysadmin$ git pull origin 8.x-5.x
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 7), reused 9 (delta 7), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
From https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm
 * branch            8.x-5.x    -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 823e673..3f7294a
Fast-forward
 includes/wf_crm_webform_preprocess.inc |    5 +----
 js/webform_civicrm_forms.js            |    6 +++---
 js/webform_civicrm_payment.js          |    2 +-
 webform_civicrm.libraries.yml          |    8 +++++++-
 4 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)`

Here are the PR specific steps:

1. navigate to your modules/webfrom_civicrm directory and pull in the PR you would like to review/test - for example:

`[karin@louise webform_civicrm]$ wget https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/128.diff`

2. patch it. Use a dry-run first - so see if there are any conflicts - the output will look something like this:

`[karin@louise webform_civicrm]$ cat 128.diff |patch -p1 --dry-run`

```
patching file includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1772 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1793 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 1810 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1835 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 1862 (offset 9 lines).
```

3. If no issues - then for real:

`[karin@louise webform_civicrm]$ cat 128.diff |patch -p1`

```
patching file includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1772 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1793 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 1810 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1835 (offset 9 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 1862 (offset 9 lines).
```

4. Check if there are any database updates to be executed (if you miss this step - you could get white screens of death). I use drush - and here's an example output:

`[karin@louise bin]$ drush updatedb`

```
Webform_civicrm  7403  Add field to create new relationship for duplicate records(expiredinactive).
Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
```

5. Ok all done -> navigate to a webform on your website and check out the new functionality! Take screenshots and note in the PR what exact steps you took - and what you compared/evaluated;
6. Bonus points for doing this on 4.7.x as well as 4.6.x

Thank you!

Comment: nice write up. updb works for updatedb and is a bit quicker to type

Comment: thanks for this write up, i do not need to use it right now but definitely going to need it

Comment: Awesome! Come time ping me on the PR you’re evaluating